# How to optimally partition a list of numbers (even in length) so that both halves are positive?

Tags: algorithm

Lets say I have a list of numbers whose length is even. How I can use dynamic programming to check whether or not the list can be split up into two separate lists (both of the same length) so that the sum of all the elements in these two lists are both positive?

For example:
Lets say I have a list: -4 5 2 1 2 -3

Then this list can be split into (-4 5 1) and (2 2 -3). The sum of the elements in both of these smaller lists are positive. Thanks!

Comment: You should have in the same list the highers and the lowers numbers. For example if you have -10, 2, 15, 3 so the lists will be {-10,15} and {2,3}.

Comment: Actually, this is not correct, I found a case that having them in the same list is not solving the issue. For example -100, -10, 90, 90, 11, 1. According to my previous answer: {-100,-10,90} and {1,11,90} and the result should have been {-100,11,90}, {-10,1,90}

Comment: I am intentionally not deleting those posts for reference to you once you get other solutions.